C++ integer values uninitialized
Here's a simple example:
#include <cstdint>

class A {
public:
  int a;
  uint16_t b;
};

#include <iostream>

int main () {
  using namespace std;
  A c;
  cout << c.a << endl;
  cout << c.b << endl;
}

I am getting random integers outputted, but from other SO answers and online -- my expectation was that integers and primitives are ZERO initialized in C++. Why is this not the case?
From my understanding, for class members, the constructor is called, if applicable

Your class does not have a constructor, and local variables are not automatically initialized.

PODs are zero-initialized when you call their constructor explicitly. E.g. uint16_t b{}; Containers like std::vector do this for you, i.e. std::vector<int> a(10); contains 10 zeros. See Default Initialization.

Therefore it is good style to always use {} even though it makes no difference for classes.

Always enable compiler warnings and read them. It'll help you fix trivial cases like this immediately

Your expectation is wrong. Integers are zero initialised in some cases but not all.

they are not random. If they were, this would be a viable way to implement a random number generator, but it isnt.
